# Why the same "Button counter code" is not working in Sandbox React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you explain what's wrong with this code. I am trying to make a simple button counter code using React using Sandbox.io IDE can anyone help.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
 
class App extends React.Component{
 
  state={
    times:0
  };
 
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello Counter</h1>
          <h2>{this.state.times} times button pressed!</h2>
          <button onClick= {() => this.setState({ times: this.state.times+1 })}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Check IDE screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOQFf.jpg)

Comment: You aren't using `App` anywhere. Did you mean to do `export default App` or something like that?

Answer (score -2):

[From React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead, eg:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});
```

therefore:

```
<button onClick= {() => this.setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, times: prevState.times+1 }) }>Click Me</button>
```